# Adding onclick event listener to a concurrent event

Tags: jquery, onclick, popup, jquery-events

I want to create a simple popup routines that will darkens the background using `overlay` class and shows the popup using `popup` class. I made this function to be a toggling function. The trick here is that I want to attach this function to the `overlay` div so that if the user click on the dark dimmed background, it will automatically closes the popup (equals to cancelling the dialog).

```
function popup (popupclass = ".popup", overlayclass = ".overlay") {
    if (!$(overlayclass).is(':visible')) {
        $(overlayclass).fadeTo('slow', 0.7);
        $(popupclass).fadeTo('slow', 0.7);
        $(popupclass).center();
        $(overlayclass).click(popup(popupclass, overlayclass));
    }
    else {
        $(overlayclass).fadeOut('slow');
        $(popupclass).fadeOut('slow');
    }
}
```

But when this function is called for the first time, the background is dimmed and the popup showed, but immediately fade out again. What's wrong?

Comment: Try `$(overlayclass).click( function() { popup(popupclass, overlayclass) } );`

Comment: It works great! That is so lame, for this is very basic of javascript, not even jquery. How can I forget? sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case

```
$(overlayclass).click(popup(popupclass, overlayclass));
```

when functional parameters passed as arguments on click event it executes and call immediately

so call the function like this

```
$(overlayclass).click( function() { 
 popup(popupclass, overlayclass) 
});
```

Comment: glad to help you friend